# QProcess readyRead before started

Tags: qt, qt4, qprocess

I am using `QProcess` for the first time, and while experimenting I noticed that `readyRead` is signaled before `started`.

I tried running `/usr/bin/echo foobar` with `QProcess`, and attached two functions to `readyRead()` and `started()` signals, and I get output in this order:

1. process start with start() method
2. dataReady() signal
3. started() signal

Now, I find a bit strange that `started()` is after `dataReady()`, because usually a process become in the running state *before* it can actually produce data, but I can not find anything about this order in the documentation, and maybe this is perfectly logical, but... Can someone explain me why this happens?

EDIT:
I add here a code that behaves like I said. I am using Qt 4.8.4 64 bit.

```
/*****************************************************************************/
// multiproc.hh
#ifndef MULTIPROC_HH
#define MULTIPROC_HH

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>
#include "node.hh"

class MultiProc: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MultiProc(QObject *parent = 0):
        QObject(parent) {
        std::cout << "MultiProc\n";

        QList<QStringList> args;
        args << (QStringList() << "/usr/bin/echo" << "Proc 0 running");
        args << (QStringList() << "/usr/bin/echo" << "Proc 1 running");
        args << (QStringList() << "/usr/bin/cat");
        args << (QStringList() << "/usr/bin/cat");
        args << (QStringList() << "/usr/bin/tee" << "/etc/hostname");

        for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i)
            _nodes << new Node(this, i, args[i]);
    }
signals:
    void finished();
public slots:
    void run() {
        std::cout << "Starting all nodes :)\n";
        foreach (Node *n, _nodes)
            n->start();
    }
private:
    QList<Node *> _nodes;
};

#endif // MULTIPROC_HH

/*****************************************************************************/
// node.hh
#ifndef NODE_HH
#define NODE_HH

#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>

class Node: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Node(QObject *parent, int id, const QStringList &args):
        QObject(parent),
        _id(id),
        _proc(new QProcess(this)),
        _args(args) {
        std::cout << "Node " << _id << " created with command "
                  << args.join(" ").toStdString() << "\n";
        connect(_proc, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(started()));
        connect(_proc, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(finished()));
        connect(_proc, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
        connect(_proc, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),
                this, SLOT(error(QProcess::ProcessError)));
    }
    void start() {
        if (_proc->state() == QProcess::NotRunning) {
            std::cout << "Starting process on node: " << _id << "\n";
            _proc->start(_args.at(0), _args.mid(1));
        }
    }
public slots:
    void started() { std::cout << "Node " << _id << " started\n"; }
    void finished() { std::cout << "Node " << _id << " finished\n"; }
    void readyRead() { std::cout << "Node " << _id << " readyRead\n"; }
    void error(QProcess::ProcessError err) {
        std::cout << "Node " << _id << " Error: " << err << "\n";
        QCoreApplication::exit(1);
    }
private:
    int _id;
    QProcess *_proc;
    QStringList _args;
};

#endif // NODE_HH

/*****************************************************************************/
// main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "multiproc.hh"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MultiProc *p = new MultiProc(&a);
    QObject::connect(p, SIGNAL(finished()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    QTimer::singleShot(0, p, SLOT(run()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

And here a piece of output:

```
Node 0 readyRead
Node 2 started
Node 0 started
Node 0 finished
Node 1 started
Node 1 readyRead
Node 4 started
Node 1 finished
Node 3 started
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, and I don't think this is logical at all.

Comment: It does not seem logical to me either :S I will try to isolate it ASAP and see if it is a Qt issue or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this with Linux and Qt 5.0.1 by first starting the process and then connecting the signals:

```
process.start("echo foo", QIODevice::ReadWrite);

connect(&process, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(started()));
connect(&process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
```

However, if I connect the signals first and then start the process, the `started()` slot is called first as excepted.

The feature you found might be considered as a bug and you might want to report it to the [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

**Edit:**

I was able to reproduce the problem with your code. I was also able to fix it by making a small change to Node's `start()` function. After calling `start()` call `waitForStarted()` before continuing. Note that by waiting only when the process state is `QProcess::Starting` you avoid problems if you try to start a non-existing program. In that case the process would never start. Of course, that can also be avoided by using some other timeout than -1 for the `waitForStarted` function.

```
void start()
{
    if (_proc->state() == QProcess::NotRunning) 
    {
        std::cout << "Starting process on node: " << _id << "\n";
        _proc->start(_args.at(0), _args.mid(1));
        if (_proc->state() == QProcess::Starting)
            _proc->waitForStarted(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I start the process after connecting.

Comment: Could you show your code? And what version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Oh, that's a nice solution. Anyway, I reported a bug/enhancement on the Qt bugtracker, because it seems a bit hackish to avoid a behaviour that does not seem natural: I think it should not happen. Anyway thanks!

Comment: I agree, my solution is only a workaround and it shouldn't be needed. Nice to hear that you reported this to the Qt bug tracker.